# How to determine what URL a closed source piece of software is connecting to? (OSX)

Tags: macos, url, sniffing

Usually I'd use Wireshark, but is there a really super quick way to determine what URL an app is pulling data from? I need to whitelist the host so that it works through a proxy server, as the app doesn't support proxies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fire up terminal and type

```
lsof -i
```

this lists all open internet connections.
 Of course you can restrict the listing to include only connections from certain executable with `-c` option. Read the man page for *lsof*. Learn to use it, it's a great little tool.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Little Snitch http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html

Great little program to catch those "phone homes". Cheap too!

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

[Charles Web Debugging Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/)

It's not quite as heavy as Wireshark so you should be able to get your results pretty quick. Short of something like Wireshark or a HTTP Debugging Proxy, I'm not sure how you'd know.